# #define var in another #define in C

Tags: c++, c

I used #define macro with variable from another #define, but the ## not work!
Please help!

```
#define _var 0b1010
#define JOIN(var1, var2) var1 ## var2

int main()
{   
    int num1 = JOIN(0b1010, 1010); // <== This works!
    int num2 = JOIN(_var, 1010); // <== This does not work!
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Define "not work". What does it do? What do you want it to do? There's no actual question in your question.

Comment: What is the exact error report?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: The C Standard does not define the `0b` prefix for binary values.

Comment: FYI `_var` is an identifier reserved by the C **and** C++ standards for use in the scope you use it in. You can trigger undefined behavior. Avoid leading underscores at file/global scope and as macro identifiers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`##` doesn't expand macros in its operands. You need to wrap `JOIN` into yet another macro to fix this:

```
#define JOIN(var1, var2) JOIN_(var1, var2)
#define JOIN_(var1, var2) var1##var2
```

Comment: You're a macro.

Comment: @SombreroChicken No you.

Comment: @SombreroChicken - And your'e a `##`!

Comment: You substituting token-paster!

Comment: Great, this works! Thank you!
If this is not useful for everyone, could i delete this?
Sorry, i'm just beginner in C. But problem i could not find anywhere!